# Avenue vs. Means

Tags: word-choice

How do you differentiate the nuances of “avenue” and “means” in the context below?:

1. Haiku can be seen as a vital avenue for grasping the unique sensibilities and culture of the Japanese people.
2. Haiku can be seen as a vital means to grasp the unique sensibilities and culture of the Japanese people.

The dictionary gives "avenue" and "means" as the translations of the Japanese term "手段".  In the monoligual dictionary, “avenue” is defined as “a choice or way of making progress towards something,” along with the most commonly used definition of “a wide street in a town or city.” Is it possible to use "avenue", to give the sense of "a vital way of making progress towards grasping the unique culture of Japanese people"?

Comment: "Haiku" is a traditional form of Japanese poetry.

Comment: Please explain the source of the quotes. Please describe how you used a dictionary, and what you found.  Please explain why this is confusing for you.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a quote. It is my own translation of a sentence extracted from a Japanese passage. The whole translation is as follows:
Haiku is one of the traditional Japanese cultural treasures. It is a form of poetry, in which a verse is made in three liners consisting of 5, 7, and 5 syllables each. Seasons and nature are typical themes of Haiku. It is often divided by a syllable known as “kire-ji,” which serves to highlight the rhythm and meanings of the poems. Essential to Haiku is the use of special word called “ki-go,” which expresses its worldview and emotions.

Comment: (continued from the avobe) To master Haiku, we need to seek guidance from Haiku teachers. They instruct us on its history, manners and composition. Haiku can be [1. or 2.] the unique sensitivity and cultures of the Japanese people.

Comment: Does the original use something like 通り.  Would you call this a metaphor in Japanese?  Does it use some thing like 手段  Pleae give details why you are considering Avenue or Means

Comment: The original does not contain any metaphors. The word in original is手段.  The word “avenue” also has a synonymous meaning to method, approach or means, but I am not really sure what the nuance is of this word. So I just wanted to know which word can better represent the idea the original has to convey.

Comment: Yes, you need to use dictionary first.  If you use a dictionary you will find that "Avenue" is a type of road. Whereas "means"  is close to "method".  The Japanese word has two different senses  You need to use a dictionary to understand which sense applies in a particular English sentence, or if there is an English word which shares the same senses.

Comment: I've voted to close as any answer would essentially be quoting the dictionary definition of "avenue" and "means".

Comment: @James K I appreciate your answers. Yes I used a dictionary, which defined “avenue” as “a choice or way of making progress towards something,” along with the most commonly used definition of “a wide street in a town or city.” But I respect your choice to close this session. Please accept my deepest gratitude. <3

Comment: If you add this to your question, it could be answered.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I sincerely appreciate your kindness and thoughtfulness. <3<3

Answer (score 1):

Many words, such as avenue, have a main meaning, and extended meanings that are figurative or metaphorical.  Avenue is a type of road.  Roads are *means* of going somewhere, so you can use avenue figuratively to mean "a means of achieving something".

So you could use either "avenue" or "means". But if you use "avenue" you are using it figuratively.  That is your choice.

(I have issues with the idea of this being "vital" - are you really saying that there is no alternative?  And with the whole suggestion of Japanese culture being any more unique than any other culture... )

Comment: Thank you again for your response.
If two words refer to the same thing, there must be at least a subtle if not straightforward difference in nuance between them. And that was my focus of interest. 

Perhaps I ought to have simply asked, “What is the nuance difference between the synonyms AVENUE (figurative) and MEANS?” It would have made my point clearer. 

My choice of “vital” was not meant to emphasize that there is no alternative (which is not what the original says, either), but that haiku is “one of the essential elements” for the understanding of Japanese mind and culture.